# How to find the current method called?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my sample, I had used property changed event. in this handler, I had an declare a method. each and every time that method fire when changing the property,
in That method, I had set the value to the property. when I set the value, it is a call to the event handler. so it's executing the circular. how to make the method call only one time?

```
private string name;
public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name= value;
            Name.PropertyChanged+=(s,e)=>
              {
                   Changed(s as string);
              };
         }
     }
private void changed(string name)
{
   Name = name;
}
```

in this code, the changed property call every time.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, because the `System.String` type has no `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Don't call Changed in the event handler?

Comment: Its really hard to know what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: i suppose its binding with wpf.. if i understand your question, if you want just one binding, you could precise Mode=OneTime in wpf..  but its hard to understand your question.....

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing is **[nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)** keyword:

```
changed(nameof(Name));
```

You can go futher and omit the need of specifying name at all by adding the following [**CallerMemberName attribute**](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2016/02/callermembername-vs-nameof-in.html) to your method's parameter:

```
private void changed([CallerMemberName]string name=null){}
```

In this case you can call this method without property name: `changed();`

I'd hazard a guess you want to implement MVVM. The most elegant way to implement it so far is to have the following base class:

```
public abstract class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected bool SetPropertyAndNotifyIfNeeded<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
         return false;
      field = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
      return true;
   }    
   protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name=null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
   }
}
```

Implementation of your MVVM:

```
class Class1:Observable
{
    public Class1()
    {            
    }    

    string propertyValue;
    public string Property
    {
        get => propertyValue;
        set => SetPropertyAndNotifyIfNeeded(ref propertyValue, value);
    }
}
```

As per your code remove subscription from your property to avoid recursive loop:

```
Name.PropertyChanged+=(s,e)=>
```

In your property call `changed(nameof(Name));`

```
class a:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

....
private string name;
public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name!=value)
            {
                name= value;
                changed();
            }
         }
     }
private void changed([CallerMemberName]string name=null)
{
   PropertyChanged.?Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));      
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your question, and I would guess, you would like to raise a Property Changed on it and set a value. Basically implement MVVM.
A really simple and quick way, would be to use a already existing Nuget package, which would simplify your job.
One that you can use is [GalaSoft.MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight).

After you add the Nuget package, you can just use it in the following way:

```
 public string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
```

RaisePropertyChanged, is going to Raise the PropertyChanged event for you (as the name itself suggests).

Comment: actually, mvvm light has a set function that raises propertychanged by name;  you would call Set(ref name, value); in the setter, which is a little bit shorter code wise.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will look into it. It's definitely shorter.